# Backbone loop sub view in main view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to loop 10 of sub view in the main view.

What I've done

**Main view** :

```
 render: function(){
        var _itemList = _.template(ItemListTem);
        $(this.el).html(_itemList);
        this.itemView = new ItemView();

        for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
            this.itemView.setElement(this.$(".itemList")).render();
        }
 }
```

**mainTemplate.html** :

```
<div class="itemList"></div>
```

**Sub View** :

```
render: function(){
        var _item = _.template(Item);
        $(this.el).html(_item)
        return this;
}
```

**Problem** :  The main view contains only a sub view.

I don't have too much experience with Backbone.js, so please excuse my ignorance if I've completely missed something here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? You want 10 `ItemView`s inside that view's `.itemList` child?

Comment: @muistooshort : `itemList` is in main view, anyways I've added some block of code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

You're updating the same instance of ItemView.

> ```
> render: function(){
>         var _itemList = _.template(ItemListTem);
>         $(this.el).html(_itemList);
>
>
>         for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
>             this.itemView = new ItemView();
>             this.itemView.setElement(this.$(".itemList")).render();
>         }
> ```
>
> subView:
>
> ```
> render: function(){
>     var _item = _.template(Item);
>     $(this.el).append(_item)
>     return this; }
> ```

Comment: There's still only view render.

Comment: Use append instead html inside your render function on subview. Using html it call jquery empty, that will clear the previous view. I updated my answer.